# Split a string into two in solidity

Tags: python

I have a list of words like below

```
["HEllO","HI","GREAT"]
```

and another list of tuples

```
[("HELLO",123),("HI",2134),("HELLO",65)]
```

If all the words in first list comes in second list atleast once then I need True as outcome else False.

Comment: in the title you have solidity, in the tag python. I am confused

Comment: @NikolayZakirov My mistake. typo..

Comment: Cool, what is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python version (based on comments from
[Pranav Hosangadi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/843953/pranav-hosangadi) and [matszwecja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9296093/matszwecja))

```
a = ["HEllO","HI","GREAT"]

b = [("HELLO",123),("HI",2134),("HELLO",65)]

not (set(a) - set(x[0] for x in b))
```

Comment: This is unnecessarily loopy. You could simply make a set of all `x[0] for x in b` first, and then check `all(y in my_set for y in a)` and it would be so much cheaper. In fact, if multiple such checks were to be necessary, it might even be prudent to create the above set _and_ a set of `a`, and simply do a set difference (as @matszwecja mentioned while I was typing my edit :-))

Comment: @PranavHosangadi you can also make a set difference A-B which I think is even more efficient.

Comment: `all(x in a for (x,y) in b)`

Comment: Good comments. Indeed seems that `[x[0] for x in b]` is recomputed every time. I'll update based on your comments